# How to manage #include of header?

Tags: c++, header, include

This is probably answered tonnes of times, but I can't seem to find the right post that talks about this issue.

Let us suppose we have classes A, B, and C that are containers of each other. This would entail that they'd have to include each other's header files. But when I do that in Visual Studio 2010, I get the error that reads "too many include files : depth = 1024".

In Java, I can have classes that import each other, but it appears the same cannot be done with C++ (why don't the compilers deal with that, really).

Anyhow, how do I get this to work?

Comment: If you really need it like that, forward declare the class instead, and store pointers or references to that class.

Comment: Since I plan to have the classes defined in separate files, how do I make forward declarations work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid circular references you may "wrap" each include file into the preprocessor #ifdef's.

File A.h:

```
#ifndef SOMEREALLYUNIQUEIDFileAincluded
#define SOMEREALLYUNIQUEIDFileAincluded

#include "B.h"

class B;

/// Here you can use pointers to B
class A
{
  // something about B*
};

#endif // SOMEREALLYUNIQUEIDFileAincluded
```

File B.h:

```
#ifndef SOMEREALLYUNIQUEIDFileBincluded
#define SOMEREALLYUNIQUEIDFileBincluded

#include "A.h"

class A;

/// Here you can use pointer to A
class B
{
  // something about A*
};

#endif // SOMEREALLYUNIQUEIDFileBincluded
```

The #ifdef's are called the "include guards"

For modern compilers instead of writing "ifdefs" you can only write

```
#pragma once
```

at the beginning of each file.

EDIT:

Then you mught use all of the headers in C.cpp:

```
#include "A.h"

#include "B.h"

void test() {}
```

Test it with "gcc -c C.cpp"  (compilation only).

EDIT2:

Some kind of a sample. A scene with renderable objects.

File Scene.h:

```
#ifndef SceneHIncluded
#define SceneHIncluded

class SceneObject;

class Scene {
public:
   void Add(SceneObject* Obj);
   void Render();
private:
   std::vector<SceneObject*> Objects;
};

#endif // SceneHIncluded
```

File Scene.cpp:

```
#include "Scene.h"
#include "SceneObject.h"

void Scene::Add() { this->Objects.pusj_back(Obj); Obj->SceneRef = this; }

void Scene::Render() {
   for(size_t j = 0 ; j < Objects.size() ; j++) { Objects[j]->Render(); }
}
```

File SceneObject.h:

```
#ifndef SceneObjHIncluded
#define SceneObjHIncluded

class Scene;

class SceneObject {
public:
   /// This is not the sample of "good" OOP, I do not suppose that
   /// SceneObject needs this reference to the scene
   Scene* SceneRef;
public:
   // No implementation here
   virtual void Render() = 0;
 };

#endif // SceneObjHIncluded
```

The implementation of the SceneObject might be some mesh with transformation, i.e.

```
 class Mesh: public SceneObject {...}
```

in the Mesh.h and Mesh.cpp files.

Comment: You're including the other class definition **and** forward declaring the class? A forward declaration is enough to use pointers.

Comment: Well, forward definitions would be sufficient, of course, but if OP asks about "recursive inclusions" also, then why not mention this ?

Comment: Last I checked doing both messes the compiler up.

Comment: Checked it and added to the end of the post. Works fine for me, shouldn't be a problem

Comment: Maybe, a useful suggestion would be to move all the "class A; class B;" stuff to a separate file as many large projects do.

Comment: @Viktor's post immediately above: Please show me how that works. I tried making a master header file with strictly forward declarations with class definitions in specific class-header files, but that scheme imploded spectacularly in Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: @Viktor's first post: So this means writing `pragma once` at beginning of every file solves all my problems?

Comment: Yes, "#pragma once" for MSVC 2003+ and gcc 3.3+ pretty much solves the recursive inclusion problems, but not the class forwarding, of course. "#pragma once" only tells the compiler not to include the file. It's an extension like Objective-C's "#import" directive

Comment: You see, the "B*" is just a pointer and when your are not calling any methods of B in A.h, there is no problem. Compiler just needs to now, that the type B is a class/struct, not something else (i.e. the array).

Comment: If you have any other problems or concrete error log (not a couple of miles long), then just edit your question (insert the code/logs) and we'll see what can be done in your case !

Comment: That is not the most portable choice of include guard macro. Identifiers beginning with an underscore and identifiers containing a double underscore are reserved for the implementation at global scope. (The latter is also reserved in all scopes.)

Comment: @CharlesBailey: modified the IDs. I hope that is not a problem now.

Comment: @chris: no, forward declarations and definitions do not mess anything up. It's idiomatic C and C++ to have both in the preprocessed input to the compiler.

Comment: How about an example of class forwarding? I'd like to see how that works out (I've tried that but failed to find a working elegant organization)

Comment: Added a sample. Not really useful as an OOP/OOD sample, just an organization of headers/cpp files

Answer (score 0):

Circular references can best be avoided by using forward-declarations for your classes and structs in your header files whenever possible. In non-circular dependencies, using a forward declaration has the added benefit of avoiding `#include`ing additional files, thus improving compile times.

In the example of 3 classes A, B, and C where A contains B, B contains C, and C contains A; you can do the following:

**a.hpp:**

```
#ifndef A_HPP
#define A_HPP

#include <memory>
#include <vector>

// Forward-declare B
struct B;

struct A
{
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<B>> bs;
};

#endif
```

**b.hpp:**

```
#ifndef B_HPP
#define B_HPP

#include <memory>
#include <vector>

// Forward-declare C
struct C;

struct B
{
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<C>> cs;
};

#endif
```

**c.hpp:**

```
#ifndef C_HPP
#define C_HPP

#include <memory>
#include <vector>

// Forward-declare A
struct A;

struct C
{
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>> as;
};

#endif
```

**main.cpp:**

```
#include "a.hpp"
#include "b.hpp"
#include "c.hpp"

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<A> a(new A);
    std::shared_ptr<B> b(new B);
    std::shared_ptr<C> c(new C);

    a->bs.push_back(b);
    b->cs.push_back(c);
    c->as.push_back(a);
}
```

Example compiles in g++-4.7 (*the concept applies identically to c++98, you just can't use* `shared_ptr<>`):

```
g++ -std=c++11 -pedantic main.cpp
```

It's important in cases like this if you need to use functionality from one of your dependent classes that you use that functionality in it's corresponding **.cpp** file. So anything other than the name of the class itself. When **a.cpp** `#include`s the headers *a.hpp* & *b.hpp*, **b.cpp** `#include`s *b.hpp* & *c.hpp*, and **c.cpp** `#include`s *c.hpp* & *a.hpp* there won't be a problem with circular includes because each **.cpp** file is compiled into its own translation unit and the linker will be able to sort out multiple class definitions without a problem, just so long as they're identical (which they will be, as they come from the same files).

Comment: Now, what if I want to have A, B, and C all be containers of each other? Would the program implode if I forward declare the same class in multiple headers?